# What kind of 'for' loop is this?

Tags: for-loop, arduino, arduino-ide

My friend gave me this Arduino code:

```
int button;

void setup(){
    pinMode(12, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
    for(button; button == HIGH; button == digitalRead(12)) { //This line
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

The line commented with "this line" is unclear to me.

I've always seen a `for` loop like:

```
for (init; condition; increment)
```

Also used in different ways, like:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){}
for(;;){}
```

And so on, but I've never seen something like the code I got from my friend.

It does compile on the Arduino IDE, so what is the meaning of this specific `for` loop?

In other words, what kind of loop is it, and how does it work?

Comment: for loops don't have to increment, the syntax is more like `for(run_once_at_start; conditions_to_check_every_loop; actions_to_perform_every_loop)`

Also, note that it's broken code, `==` has no side effects and nothing is done. I think your friend means `=`

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 i think he just meant `==` as it compiles and runs properly

Comment: Sure, it compiles and runs properly, as do plenty of `logical` errors. It won't do anything though, he's comparing the value of digitalRead on pin 12 to button and not doing anything with the results. `button == digitalRead(12)` could be completely omitted and it would produce the same results. In fact, I bet you the compiler optimized it out anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop:

```
for(button; button == HIGH; button == digitalRead(12))
```

is equivalent to:

```
button; // does nothing - should probably be  `button = HIGH;` ?
while (button == HIGH)   // break out of loop when button != HIGH
{
    //do something here
    button == digitalRead(12); // comparison - should probably be assignment ?
}
```

Note: I suspect the whole loop is buggy and should probably read:

```
for (button = HIGH; button == HIGH; button = digitalRead(12))
    // do something here
```

Comment: "probably" does nothing?  When might it do something?

Comment: Oops - I thought that button might be a macro or something but I see now that it's declared as `int button;` so yes, it does nothing.

Comment: `digitalRead()` may or may not have a side effect. It most probably has. That is the *probable* here, IMHO

Comment: `digitalRead` reads the logic level on a GPIO pin. It doesn't normally have any side-effect unless there's an unusual hardware configuration. It cannot affect the value of `button`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's interpret this literally.  Converts to while loop as:

```
button; // does nothing
while(button == HIGH) { // clear
    // do stuff
    button == digitalRead(12); // same as digitalRead(12);
}
```

This code *really* should be setting off a lot of IDE or compiler warnings.  Anyway my answer is correct, that's what it literally converts to.  Note that `button == digitalRead(12)` is valid but does nothing with the result of the comparison.

Most likely the code is buggy.  One hypothesis is the `==` should be `=`.